# Open vendor app's on Android when push notifications are received (automatically 'press' notification)

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

Firstly to save confusion, I am not creating an app myself. This question relates to apps I have downloaded from google play. When receiving a notification from an app, lets say for example ebay's app, does anyone know if it's possible to  program android to press this notification automatically the second it arrives and thus open it on the phone without human interaction? Are there any app's that would allow me to configure this, or alternatively any way to change android settings or code this myself in the operating system? I do apologise if this is a noobie question. I have very little experience of android- I only got a smart phone for the first time recently after years of reluctance, but I am becoming interested in its potential.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is possible, you will receive the callback in broadcast receiver and can start an activity but you should never do it.

The user decide what app he opens, opening an app without the user interaction is a bad decision and probably will make people uninstall your app.

Comment: I don't have an app, I'm talking about using it to open apps i've downloaded myself onto my phone from google play- for examples ebay's app. I want to know if I can somehow allow my phone to open these apps automatically through the notifications.

Comment: I see, you will need an app. In your app you can register to receive all notifications of your phone and decide what to do accordingly to the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom broadcast receiver. and it in your manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".Myreciever" android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="app.celebcabs.NEWRIDER"/></intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```